# Psd Icon in window not showing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using CS3 on winXP. After using CS3 for a couple months, I felt that I no longer needed cs3 on my computer, and I uninstalled it.and moved to cs4,now today i found some file missing in cs4 so i have to rollback to cs3 again,now cs3 is working fine but its not showing PSD thumbnails in windows,its creating a big issue for me its showing like this.

[image]

later on  it was showing like default save icon of .psd something like this :

[image]

Now i don't know whats the issue i Reinstalled everything twice but still its showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

http://blog.ashfame.com/2008/03/change-icons-file-types/

In the last step try to point to Photoshop.exe file - it may have icons embedded inside.

I haven't tried but it's my best guess